# ASP.NET Update Panel Updates only Once

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, partial-postback

Hi I have an Update Panel like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Updatepanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadioButtons1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDown1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDown2" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDown3" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="LabelToUpdate"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I want to update the label everytime one of the above triggers happens.

The first time I trigger it everything works perfectly fine. But after that there are no more updates even if I change anything (It is like  all Control's `AutoPostBack` get set to false after the first Partial Post back, so nothing happens when i change the selection a second time).

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "all the triggers AutoPostBack get set to false"?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for that confusion. I mean nothing will post back anymore on the page. When I change the value of the drop downs and the radio button lists nothing happens. It is like they don't do anymore postbacks

Comment: Are you databinding these controls on postback? You should embed it in an `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`-check. Are these controls dynamically created? You know that the control-id must be the same on every postback to trigger the events? Have you debugged to see if page_load is handled? Do you see any javascript errors on page?

Comment: 1- Databinding on postback : no
2- embed it in an if(!Page.IsPostBack) : I use this check to set the default values. I didn't undertand what you mean.
3- Are these controls dynamically created?: No. But I am creating other controls on postbacks. (I create other labels in the update panel)
4- the control-id must be the same on every postback: It is the same I don't change anything with the controls that trigger the update panel.
5-page_load is handled? It is not handled. Nothing happens when I change the selections
6- Do you see any javascript errors on page: No- I'm not using any javascript

Comment: Maybe you should post the actual code

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste this .. works fine :)

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtons1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="4"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="4"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="4"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDown3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="4"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Updatepanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="RadioButtons1" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDown1" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDown2" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDown3" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="LabelToUpdate"><%= "rad: " + RadioButtons1.SelectedItem.Text + "<br />" + "drop1: " + DropDown1.SelectedItem.Text + "<br />" + "drop2: " + DropDown2.SelectedItem.Text + "<br />" + "drop3: " + DropDown3.SelectedItem.Text %></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```